# Proxying MultiPart form requests in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a Grails controller that receives a DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest like so:

```
def myController() {
    DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest proxyRequest = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request
}
```

This controller acts as a proxy by taking pieces of this request and then resends the request to another destination.

For non-multipart requests, this worked fine, I did something like:

```
IProxyService service = (IProxyService) clientFactory.create()
Response response = service.doPOST(proxyRequest.getRequestBody())
```

Where proxyRequest.getRequestBody() contains a JSON block containing the request payload.

However, I do not know how to get this to work with multipart request payload, since the request body is no longer a simple block of JSON, but something like the following (taken from Chrome devtools):

[image]

How can I can pass this request payload through using my proxy service above, where doPost takes a String?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
def parameterValue = request.getParameter("parameterName")
```

to get the parameter value?
If you see the method signatures for DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest you will see there are methods for getting the files and other parameters separately because the request body is getting used to both upload the file and to pass in other parameters.